# QuickSort by reading a numerical txt file using Python

Tags: python, quicksort

I have updated my program, it did not give me an error. However it gave me the same txt file without sorting

txt_array.txt
54044
14108
79294
29649
25260
60660
2995
53777
49689
9083

```
#QuickSort with first element to be a pivot element

def choosePivot(arr, l, r): 
        i = (l - 1) #first index
        pivot = arr[l] #first element to be a pivot
    
        for j in range(l+1, r+1):
                if arr[j] < pivot:
                    arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i] #swapping
                    i=i+1 #increment i
        position = i-1 #checking position
        arr[l], arr[r] = arr[position], arr[l]
        return position

def quickSort(arr, l, r):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr
    if l < r:
        p = choosePivot(arr, l, r)
        quickSort(arr, l, p-1)
        quickSort(arr, p+1, r)

def readFile(filename, l):
    # f = open(filename, "r")
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            l.append(int(line))

    if f.closed == False:
        f.close()

def main ():
    txt_array = []
    size = len(txt_array)
    readFile("array.txt", txt_array)
    print (txt_array[:]) #Appear all numbers of the array
    print ("Numbers of given: " + str(len(txt_array)))
    quickSort(txt_array, 0,size-1)
    print("Sorted array: " + str(txt_array))
    return 0 
main()
```

my outpout is

[54044, 14108, 79294, 29649, 25260, 60660, 2995, 53777, 49689, 9083]

Numbers of given: 10

Sorted array: [54044, 14108, 79294, 29649, 25260, 60660, 2995, 53777, 49689, 9083]

Answer (score 1):

Error should specify line number, but I suspect it's:

`C,txt_array = quickSort(txt_array, 0,size-1)`

In this line you unpack whatever quickSort returned, which might be None in which case it would fail with that error.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you get it on the line `C, txt_array = quickSort(txt_array, 0, size-1)`, am i right?

In the line `C, txt_array = quickSort(txt_array, 0, size-1)` you are trying to unpack the returned value into to variables `C` and `txt_array` which throws the error you mention since the function doesn't return any value, meaning it is `None`.

**To solve it**: Since the function operates on an array that is in the same scope, it should be enough to replace `C, txt_array = quickSort(txt_array, 0, size-1)` with `quickSort(txt_array, 0, size-1)`and `txt_array` should still be sorted. (However, i can't answer on what C is expected to be so that you would need to fix separately)

**EDIT:** in the example below i substituted the code in your quicksort and choosePivot functions against functions [from this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-quicksort/) and then the principle i explain in my answer below is illustrated.

```py
# ------- START code borrowed from tutorial
def partition(arr, low, high): 
    i = (low-1)
    pivot = arr[high]
    for j in range(low, high):
        if arr[j] <= pivot: 
            i = i+1
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i] 
    arr[i+1], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i+1] 
    return (i+1) 
  
def quickSort(arr, low, high): 
    if len(arr) == 1: 
        return arr 
    if low < high: 
        pi = partition(arr, low, high) 
        quickSort(arr, low, pi-1) 
        quickSort(arr, pi+1, high) 

# ------- END code borrowed from tutorial

def readFile(filename, l):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            l.append(int(line))

    if f.closed == False:
        f.close()

  
def main():
    txt_array = []
    readFile("array.txt", txt_array)
    size = len(txt_array)
    print (txt_array[:]) #Appear all numbers of the array
    print ("Numbers of given: " + str(len(txt_array)))
    quickSort(txt_array, 0, size-1)
    print("Sorted array: " + str(txt_array))

main()
```

This would output

```
[54044, 14108, 79294, 29649, 25260, 60660, 2995, 53777, 49689, 9083]
Numbers of given: 10
Sorted array: [2995, 9083, 14108, 25260, 29649, 49689, 53777, 54044, 60660, 79294]
```

Comment: Nice, though if you have to assemble array after quick sort aren't you really merge sorting? ;)

Comment: @yjay Hmm i see now that you are calling the same array recursively and i was mistaking it for being split into smaller arrays and recursively called. Updating my answer a bit. stay tuned! :D

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I was trying to print out console that is why I assigned C to be a sorted array and print(C). I replaced C, txt_array = quickSort(txt_array, 0, size-1) with quickSort(txt_array, 0, size-1)and txt_array. It gave me the same txt_array in the txt file without sorting.

Comment: @QuangT Hmm ok. could you update your description with the code you are running? The provided code doesn't run

Comment: @QuangT I still can't make the code in the example  run either with python 2.7 or python 3. I just get an index out of range error.

Comment: That is strange because I ran into it with no error with python3 hmm 

Comment: @QuangT Sorry but there are many things that you need to debug. `size` is set just after declaring the empty variable, meaning that size will always be 0 in your code above. That leads to the quicksort never doing anything since `l < r` will always be `False` due to having values 0 < -1. 

I got index out of range error due to removing the readFile function and just setting the txt_array with the values directly. That's why i couldn't run the code.

Comment: @QuangT Check my updated answer where i substitute your functions to show that the principle i explained works.

Comment: Thank you so much :D